# name of this cascade-like graph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a common name for the following graph?

[image]

Comment: Upside down tree? That would be my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, we have, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)):

> A rooted tree may be directed, called a **directed rooted tree**, either making all its edges point away from the root—in which case it is called an **arborescence**, **branching**, or **out-tree**—or making all its edges point towards the root—in which case it is called an **anti-arborescence** or **in-tree**.

So what we have here is clearly a kind of anti-arborescence or in-tree. I'll stick to the shorter term, but it's entirely a matter of taste.

More precisely, it is an infinite **binary** in-tree: a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) is any tree in which each node has at most two children, so it's reasonable to call this structure (in which each node has at most two parents) a binary in-tree.

To describe this specific graph, we could say that it's an infinite binary in-tree with a **[branching factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_factor)** of $2$ in odd levels and a branching factor of $1$ in even levels (or vice versa, depending on whether you number your levels from $0$ or $1$). Actually, with this phrasing, the qualifier "binary" is redundant, and could be omitted.